# Changing the subtitle in Ag-Grid react when you use refreshCells to regenerate a chart

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using Ag-Grid React, which I'm new to.
I have a drop-down that allows you to switch to different data sets that are being called from AWS into a line chart via the refreshCells function.
The chart refreshes fine when you select something from the drop-down but I would also like to change the subtitle of the line chart to match the data being pulled (the selected drop-down value).
Is this possible to do with the refreshCells function after the page has initially loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while defining your `gridOptions` object define `processChartOptions` as shown below.

this method gets called whenever chart is redrawn due to change in underlying data. you can use the params object to dynamically set the title/subtitle values.

```js
function processChartOptions(params) {
  var options = params.options;

  console.log('chart options:', options);

  options.title.enabled = true;
  options.title.text = 'your title here';
  options.title.fontStyle = 'italic';
  options.title.fontWeight = '600';
  options.title.fontSize = 18;
  options.title.fontFamily = 'Impact, sans-serif';
  options.title.color = '#414182';

  options.subtitle.enabled = true;
  options.subtitle.text = 'your subtitle here';
  options.subtitle.fontSize = 14;
  options.subtitle.fontFamily = 'Monaco, monospace';
  options.subtitle.color = 'rgb(100, 100, 100)';

  return options;
}
```

here is a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/23HeQhaNY4r4yipd).

Comment: I haven't been able to successfully pass any variables into that function post render. I can pass in successfully on the initial load but the refresh function only reloads the chart columns not the rest of the page.So it doesn't re-pull the chartOptions. I might be wrong, so I'll try this again. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer with plunkr Demo which changes title and subtitle dynamically. you have to make sure that the reference you are using in ProcessChartOptions method are also available to you in refreshCells. using variable whose scope is available in both method will help you.

Comment: Thanks! I was able use this information to get the values to pass. Much appreciated Sandeep!!